# octokit return 500 while curl works fine

Tags: github, github-api, octokit

I'm using jdcargile/ms-teams-notification for sending github notification to MS Teams. I use Github enterprise.
This action uses octokit.
And I'm getting following error.

```
RequestError [HttpError]: request to https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/commits/43r325yy4r2568g23421233cfrr45001failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT <ip>:443
at /runner/_work/_actions/<org>/<repo>/v1.4/dist/index.js:15551:11
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
status: 500,
headers: {},
request: {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/commits/43r325yy4r2568g23421233cfrr45001',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    'user-agent': 'octokit-rest.js/17.11.2 octokit-core.js/2.5.4 Node.js/20.8.1 (Linux 5.10; x64)',
    authorization: 'token [REDACTED]'
  },
  request: { hook: [Function: bound bound register] }
  }
}
```

The thing is that this get request done with curl (with the same token) from the same machine works fine.
Do have any idea what can be potential reason?
Thanks in advance!